# jQuery find and remove string

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help me to find all the "/" and remove them with jQuery please? HTML below:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>a /</li>
  <li>b /</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: jquery can't find text, just elements. You'll have to instead find elements that have said text, then use javascript string manipulation to do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find each item, and then looping through to remove the `/`:

```
$("li:contains('/')").each(function(){
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(' /',''));
});
```

You'll need to modify for variances, but based on the HTML shown this will do the trick.